# CloudKit push notification subscription not working

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm trying to subscribe to push notifications using CloudKit. I'm getting this error:

```
<CKError 0x170c5b1e0: "Unknown Item" (11/2003); server message = "could not find required field fieldID="25""
```

from this code:

```
let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "PlayerData", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE"), options: CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordCreation)
let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
notificationInfo.shouldBadge = false
subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
PublicDb.saveSubscription(subscription, completionHandler: { (returnedSubscription: CKSubscription!, error: NSError!) in
     println("\(error)")
})
```

But I don't have a field called "fieldID" nor I have any kind of reference to it in my entire project. I don't know where the 25 comes from either. It still happens if I change my record type and/or NSPredicate.

I also tried setting this but nothing

```
notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
```

This used to work for me, but now I cannot make it work anymore. Seems like my database got corrupted somewhere. I tried deleting the record type and recreating but no luck.

Comment: It sounds like something got messed up with your CloudKit container. Is this a recently created container, or did you create it during the iOS 8 betas? Does this subscription work if you try it against a new container? If you file a radar with your container name and [CloudKit logs](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/icloud/#icloud-drive) then Apple can clean up your container server-side if it's broken.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually fixed it by resetting the development environment. fieldID=25 was such a mystery. It seems like my data somehow got connected to someone else's database. I checked all my other containers and it didn't have any reference to "fieldID"

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. If this happens again a radar would be great so that if there is a bug on the server side we can get it fixed.

Comment: @farktronix Got it when create a subscription on iPhone 5s `<CKError 0x144525860: "Unknown Item" (11/2003); server message = "did not find required record type: _sub_trigger_sub_4ce2f1036aa884fc21ca48632a7b8095"; uuid = 984FDC7B-71B6-4762-A18C-30DE0F7F8F09; container ID = "my container">` Subscription created on the other device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed it by resetting the development environment. Hopefully same thing doesn't happen on prod.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

This same thing just happened to me. I don't think fieldID is due to someone else's database, but rather part of Apples underlying database structure. Unfortunately that read-out gives us developers zero information. The resetting of the development environment fixed my issue as well. Worth noting that this happened after changing the attribute type of a record that was specifically being referenced in a subscription. I had kept the attribute name but changed its type.

Comment: I think you're onto something. It happened to me when I _removed_ a field from a record type that was specifically referenced by some subscriptions. Unfortunately adding back the removed field didn't help, nor did removing the referenced records. I had to reset the environment.